# CasperJS and cronjob

Tags: phantomjs, cron, casperjs

so I have phantomJS and casperJS installed, everything is working fine, but I'm trying to add my casperJS file to cronjob (ubuntu) and I'm getting error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/casperjs: not found
```

My crontab file:

> 0 */1 * * *  PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs
>   /usr/local/bin/casperjs /usr/local/share/casper-test/test.js 2>&1

Any Ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use several commands on one line, you have to separate them with a semicolon:

> 0 */1 * * * PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs **;** /usr/local/bin/casperjs /usr/local/share/casper-test/test.js 2>&1

Or, if you need to execute commands sequentially and only progress to next if the previous has been successful, use && operator.

For better readability you could just put those commands in a shell script and run that from cron.

Comment: Oh, shell script was what I was looking for I think. Thank you!